# ExceptionsManager.js:74 TypeError: RNOneSignal.didSetNotificationOpenedHandler is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> i am using react-native-onesignal 3.3.2, i got the following error ,is there any solution

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-onesignal

```
 ExceptionsManager.js:74 TypeError: RNOneSignal.didSetNotificationOpenedHandler is not a function

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

Comment: Hai Jamal @try https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/682